# FFmpeg - How to cut .m4a song without losing quality?

Tags: ffmpeg, music, m4a

I would like to cut a song from 1:45 to the end (I mean, I would like to keep only the part from 0:00 to 1:45). But **I don't want to lose the quality of the song**. How can I to do that using FFmpeg?

**Edit**: I mean, I have a song that is long 2:20 minutes. I would like to export it from the start till 1:45 minutes and remove the part after 1:45, without losing the quality of the song

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
ffmpeg -i input.file -t 105 -acodec copy -vcodec copy output.file
```

`-t` set the length to be 105 seconds =  1:45 minutes
`-acodec` and `-vcodec` are set to copy so you do not change the codes, just copy fro source

to start removing from some position the sound for example you can use command like:

```
ffmpeg -i input.file -ss 1:45.001  -an -vcodec copy output.file
```

this will start dropping audio from position 1:45.001 (the last is in milliseconds)

This will work on environment where the delimiter for digital point is dot (`.`)
To extract only part of song it will be:

```
ffmpeg -i input.m4a -ss 0 -t 1:45.001  -acodec copy output.m4a
```

this will copy one minute, 45 seconds and one millisecond from audio file `input.m4a` to file `output.m4a`. Starting from position 0 of the input file

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Sorry, I mean that I want to remove the audio from the song. I would like to keep the song **without** the part from "1:45". I tried your command but it gives me the audio from "1:45" to the end. Also, is there a way to put milliseconds?

Comment: @woyim46107, check my edited answer

Comment: thank you, I tried but it does not works, it gives me this error "Output file #0 does not contain any stream". Btw, I edited the question to make it more clean

Comment: @woyim46107, this is opposite of what you explain in comment! And clarify, do we talk about audio, audio+video. And what part you want to be in output file.

Comment: it's just an audio, a song .m4a. In output file I would like to have the song from start till 1:45

Comment: @woyim46107, check my last edit

Comment: thank you so much, it worked. If I understood correctly, `-ss 0` means that it will start from the beginning, `-t 1:45.001` means that it will do it till 1 minute and 45 seconds and 1 milliseconds, `-acodec copy` means that it will copy the content from source without rencoding, so I can be 100% sure that the output will **not** lose quality, but it will be the same quality of the source because the content is the same. Right?

Comment: I wonder if putting `-t 105` before `-i` avoids the need of `-ss 0`.

Comment: @TomYan I tried, yes I can to avoid it `-ss 0`, no need to put `-t` before the `-i`. This is the final command: `ffmpeg -i "input.m4a" -t "00:01:45.673" -acodec copy output.m4a` it seems to work perfectly